# Does TypeRex support OCaml 4.00.1?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, typerex

Hi I would like to use TypeRex, but it says

```
$ ./configure 
checking for ocamlc... ocamlc
OCaml version is 4.00.1
OCaml library path is /usr/local/lib/ocaml
checking for ocamlopt... ocamlopt
checking for ocamlc.opt... ocamlc.opt
checking for ocamlopt.opt... ocamlopt.opt
checking for ocaml... ocaml
checking for ocamldep.opt... ocamldep.opt
checking for ocamlmktop... ocamlmktop
checking for ocamlmklib... ocamlmklib
checking for ocamldoc... ocamldoc
checking for ocamlbuild... ocamlbuild
checking for camlp4... camlp4
checking for camlp4boot... camlp4boot
checking for camlp4o... camlp4o
checking for camlp4of... camlp4of
checking for camlp4oof... camlp4oof
checking for camlp4orf... camlp4orf
checking for camlp4prof... camlp4prof
checking for camlp4r... camlp4r
checking for camlp4rf... camlp4rf
configure: error: Your version of OCaml: 4.00.1 is not supported
```

**Does TypeRex support OCaml 4.00.1?**

---

I further followed this page http://www.typerex.org/manual-setup.html

I used this command

```
$./configure --disable-version-check EMACS=aquamacs
```

It doesn't complain, but after I use

```
$ make
```

it says

```
mkdir -p ./_obuild
ocamlc -o ./_obuild/unixrun -make-runtime unix.cma
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while building custom runtime system
make: *** [_obuild/unixrun] Error 2
```

**Anyone can help me with this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typerex [doesn't work](https://github.com/OCamlPro/typerex/issues/59) out of the box with OCaml 4.00.X (follow the discussion). You'll have to wait, "[it is not dead, it is just sleeping for a while](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2012-12/msg00148.html)".

Comment: I believe you can try out the development version in the typerex2 branch.